# How to switch back to graphical vt

Tags: virtual-console

In Ubuntu 17.04 I can easily press Alt-Ctrl and f1 to f6 to switch between the virtual terminals in text mode, but the usual Alt-Ctrl f7 (or any of the other f keys) does not take be back to the graphical console. How should I get back?

Comment: Keep going , could be F8 - F12, although I would guess F1 or F8 at this point.

Comment: Are you going to upgrade to 17.10?

Comment: No none of the f keys get me back I have tried f1 to f12. f1 to f6 switch the text mode virtual terminals f7 to f12 do nothing.

Comment: not going to update yet, as later kernel do not work on my laptop at the moment.

Comment: For me `sudo chvt 7` did that (on Linux Mint 21).